# Geo-location in attendance module Odoo

Tags: odoo

I'm new to ODOO and looking for a way to capture **Geo-location in the attendance module** of ODOO. Need to capture both check-in and check-out locations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this module , it captures geolocation : https://odoo-community.org/shop/product/hr-attendance-geolocation-5170

Comment: I've accepted the answer as it works for web, but i'm looking for android app too.

Comment: I think you can try capturing the geo-location by opening the blank page but for this you have to give location access for respective devices.